# Can't present view controller in a UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I have multiple container views embedded into one navigation controller. Now I'm trying to use `UIPopoverController` to display a view. This view was already presented to the user before - it was in a container view embedded in a navigation controller. If I try to present the view again in a popover I get

> Application tried to present modally an active controller

But the view isn't active. It's only somewhere in the navigation controller stack. Does this mean that you can present every view only one time?

**Edit:**

The structure for this problem looks like the following:

View Controller > Container A (VC1, VC2, VC3) > Container B (VC2, VC4)

Now on Container B VC3 should be presented as a popup. An event is raised on VC2 in Container B (C# event). Container B should present the popup --> The app crashes and I get the above error message.

Now I tried to present the popup directly from VC2. This seems to work. Perhaps it's a problem because I reused the popover instance from Container B. I'll check that out.

Comment: Is a navigation controller the appropriate data holder in this case? Sounds like you're not doing any navigational tasks with the view controllers.

Comment: I'm navigating from one container to the next. This works so far except the `UIPopoverController` thing.

Comment: Ah I get it. Would it be possible for the VC to have its own instance of the view so you don't have to reuse it?

Comment: Each of the two containers instantiate the subview controller in it's constructor. There should be two separate instances. I don't know where such a reuse should come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I created a new instance of `UIPopoverController` in Container B where the event is catched. It works as expected and doesn't crash anymore.

Still don't know why I can't reuse the popover with `contentViewController`. Or is it because I'm using `presentPopoverFromRect` and another time `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem`?